# Select no php reconhece apenas uma variável

Tags: php, sql, data

Preciso buscar datas no banco de dados e compará-las com as datas geradas por um `for`. Se forem iguais, ficam vermelhas.

Já consegui pegar os valores por um `Select` e armazená-los num array usando outro `for`, faço a comparação e ele imprime os valores que passei pro array, porém apenas uma das datas fica em vermelho.

Fiz o teste e apenas a com maior valor de ID (referente as datas que são buscadas no banco e armazenadas no array) está sendo comparada e "pintada" de vermelho. Já fiz o teste trocando os ids (pois o banco só possui duas datas a serem comparadas mesmo) e a que fica com o ID maior sempre fica vermelha.

Segue o código abaixo. Acredito que o problema pode estar no modo de comparação ou até mesmo na forma como o banco seleciona os dados.

```
for($i=0;$i<=$nr_dias;$i++){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM expedientes_diferenciados";
    if ($result = $conexao->query($query)) {
        /* fetch object array */
        $k=0;
        while ($obj = $result->fetch_object() and $k<2) {                           
                $diaind=$obj->data;
                $array1[$k]= date("d-m-Y", strtotime($diaind));
                $motivo[$k] =$obj->motivo;
                $k++;
    }}

    $dia = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+$i,date("Y")));
    $dia_sql = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+$i,date("Y")));
    $semana=$dias_semana[date("D",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+$i,date("Y")))];
    $lock_cafe="";$lock_almoco="";$lock_jantar="";

    //Condicionais
    $b=0;
    while($b<2){    
        if($semana=="Sábado" or $semana=="Domingo" or $dia==$array1[$b]) {
            $cor = "red";
            $msg_expediente = "Sem expediente<br>";
            echo $array1[$b];
        }
        else{
            $msg_expediente = "Expediente normal<br>";
            $cor = "white";
        }
        $b++;
    }
}
```

Comment: mano você tem ideia, de que você está resetando a variavel $k=0 e $b=0 pelo loop do seu for inicial.. você deveria declarar estás duas variáveis fora do laço FOR. e você também não esta incrementando $k em lugar nenhum para ele chegar ao valor 2. você também deve colocar as comparações entre () dentro do seu while.. ex: while(($obj = $result->fetch_object())) AND ($a>2))

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM expedientes_diferenciados";
if ($result = $conexao->query($query)) {
    /* fetch object array */
    $k=0;
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object() and $k<2) {                           
            $diaind=$obj->data;
            $array1[$k]= date("d-m-Y", strtotime($diaind));
            $motivo[$k] =$obj->motivo;
            $k++;
}}
```

Este bloco pode estar FORA do primeiro FOR, até por questão de performance, como são 2 campos, não afeta muito, mais imagina com 200000 ou mais, ele vai recuperar a cada laço do for, e não é dependende dos valores do loop

Dentro do segundo while, tem que haver um foreach, para ele percorrer os dados do array1, ai o if deve comparar esses valores, senão na segunda volta do while, os valores da volta 1 são sobrepostos, ai sempre a saída desse segundo while é o do ultimo valor percorrido....